# JobScheduler Error?

Tags: android

When I schedule the JobScheduler in Application#onCreate() method, Sometimes got the below error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{com.brain.MyJobService}
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1688)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
    at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule(IJobScheduler.java:158)
    at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:42)
    at com.brain.MyScanJobService.configSchedule(MyJobService.java:341)
    at com.brain.MyJobService.configSchedule(MyJobService.java:317)
    at com.miui.optimizecenter.ApplicationDelegate$1.run(ApplicationDelegate.java:85)
```

My Code are simply as follows :

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service
        android:name="com.brain.MyJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
</service>
```

**MyJobService**

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {
    // ...
    public static void scheduleJob(Context context){
        // ...
        JobInfo scanJob = new JobInfo.Builder(MY_JOB_ID, new ComponentName(context, MyJobService.class))
                            .setPeriodic(1000*100)
                            .setPersisted(true)
                            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
                            .build();
        // tag2
        jobScheduler.schedule(scanJob)
    }
    // ...
}
```

**ApplicationDelegate#onCreate()**

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        MyJobScheduler.scheduleJob();
    }).start()
}
```

It is work good with the same config method, except in the Application#onCreate() method.

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

try to add `android:exported="true"` in the manifest declaration:

```
<service
        android:name="com.brain.MyJobService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
</service>
```